# datetime from string with flexible string format

Tags: python, python-datetime

I'm parsing date time from string in Python. I like the fact that in pandas, I can define 1 single format, but pandas still allows me to be flexible in my input. As follows

```
>>> format = '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
>>> pd.to_datetime('20200106 23:00', format=format)
Timestamp('2020-01-06 23:00:00')          ## OK
>>> pd.to_datetime('20200106 23:00:00', format=format)
Timestamp('2020-01-06 23:00:00')          ## OK
>>> pd.to_datetime('20200106 23:00:00.000', format=format)
Timestamp('2020-01-06 23:00:00')          ## still ok
```

With Pandas, I can accept user input that looks like `%H:%M` or `%H:%M:%S`, or `%H:%M:S.%f`. As long as it doesn't violate the original format, it's fine. I like this flexibility.

Does that same behavior exist in datetime?

```
>>> datetime.strptime('20200106 23:00:00.000000', format)
datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 6, 23, 0)                 ## OK
>>> datetime.strptime('20200106 23:00:00', format)   ## NOT OK
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 565, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
     (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '20200106 23:00:00' does not match format '%Y%m%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
```

strptime doesn't like it. What am I supposed to do? List *all* formats that user might put in? And do a bunch of tries?

Comment: No, this doesn't exist in stdlib `datetime`.  Use a third-party library such as `python-dateutil` or `pendulum`.

Comment: [python-dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) will accept (but ignore) the fractional seconds.

Answer (score 2):

There's a package(s) for that:

- [arrow](https://pypi.org/project/arrow/)
- [maya](https://pypi.org/project/maya/)

...and others. You can also roll your own regex if you find inputs that these packages don't parse to your liking.

Comment: **Here's an article that compares six of them** (Dateutil, Arrow, Moment, Maya, Delorean, Freezegun):  [6 Python datetime libraries - Opensource](https://opensource.com/article/18/4/python-datetime-libraries).  It doesn't address the fractional second issue directly, and a couple of these (e.g., Maya) seem to be meta-libraries that sit on top of some of the other ones.  Here's an article that discusses **parsing in Maya, dateutil, and Arrow** [Converting Strings to datetime in Python](https://stackabuse.com/converting-strings-to-datetime-in-python/).  Just as an FYI for people looking.

Answer (score 0):

`dateparser` https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/ can take flexible form of datetime input, also have non-English language support

```py
>>> import dateparser
>>> dateparser.parse('12/12/12')
datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 12, 0, 0)
>>> dateparser.parse('Fri, 12 Dec 2014 10:55:50')
datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 12, 10, 55, 50)
>>> dateparser.parse('Martes 21 de Octubre de 2014')  # Spanish (Tuesday 21 October 2014)
datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 21, 0, 0)
>>> dateparser.parse('Le 11 Décembre 2014 à 09:00')  # French (11 December 2014 at 09:00)
datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 11, 9, 0)
>>> dateparser.parse('13 января 2015 г. в 13:34')  # Russian (13 January 2015 at 13:34)
datetime.datetime(2015, 1, 13, 13, 34)
>>> dateparser.parse('1 เดือนตุลาคม 2005, 1:00 AM')  # Thai (1 October 2005, 1:00 AM)
datetime.datetime(2005, 10, 1, 1, 0)
```